How significant is the horror content in Season of Ghosts?
I'm considering running the Pathfinder adventure Season of Ghosts. The adventure describes itself as a "horror-themed" adventure. I want to do my due diligence and make sure the content is appropriate for my table.
How significant is the horror content of the adventure? Is it primarily supernatural stuff (like ghosts, which the title mentions), or is there more visceral kinds of horror? For example, are there graphic images or content I may need to done down, or topics that may require a "trigger warning"?

There's a Specific Content Warning for Book 3
This section is included at the start of the book for GM's to know what goes beyond the Pathfinder Baseline described in the Player Core and GM Core books.

 While Pathfinder Adventure Path #198: No Breath to Cry contains typical Pathfinder action and adventure, it also includes content related to claustrophobia and being burned alive. Before you run this adventure, understand that consent from everyone at the table, including players and the Game Master, is vital to a safe and fun play experience. You should talk with your players before beginning the adventure and modify descriptions or events as appropriate.

The baseline content guidelines for Pathfinder adventures include:

You might find that your players don’t have much to
say on the topic of objectionable content and just
assume that general societal mores will keep the most
uncomfortable topics out of the game. That’s not always
enough, as that approach relies on shared assumptions
that aren’t always accurate. The following is a set of
basic assumptions that works for many groups, which
you can modify to fit your preferences and those of the
other players.

Bloodshed, injuries, and even dismemberment might be described. However, excessive descriptions of gore and cruelty should be avoided.
Because
attempts at initiating a relationship between player
characters can be uncomfortably similar to one
player hitting on another, this should generally be
avoided (and is entirely inappropriate when playing
with strangers).
Avoid excessively gross or scatological descriptions.

The following acts should never be performed by
player characters:

Torture
Rape, nonconsensual sexual contact, or sexual threats
Harm to children, including sexual abuse
Owning slaves or profiting from the slave trade
Reprehensible uses of mind-control magic


As an explicitly horror-themed campaign there is some level of buy-in/consideration required from the players, and the free player's guide for the adventure mentions a bit about Horror and Consent:

Season of Ghosts is a horror-themed campaign, and
as such, the GM and players should work together
to ensure that the themes present as this Adventure
Path unfolds will be appropriate for the game table. If
you aren’t comfortable with certain tropes or themes
common to the horror genre, speak with your GM and
the other players before beginning Season of Ghosts
to arrive at a common ground where everyone at your
table can enjoy the campaign equally.

